# Why doesn't "res.sendFile()" fucntion(Express.js) work with 'pug' files?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I am learning to use express with mongodb. I have this code & it works(it doesn't include 'pug' files though)

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/my_db");
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    nationality: String,
});
var Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);

//this code block will be reused in this question, from here
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
//to here

app.post("/person", (req, res) => {
    var myData = new Person(req.body);
    myData
        .save()
        .then((item) => {
            res.send("Name saved to database");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(400).send("Unable to save to database");
        });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```

I'm not gonna include `index.html` file here because I think it is unnecessary. However when I'm going to do the same thing(input data to a database through a from) using 'pug' files the code doesn't output anything, but automatically download the 'pug' file that I used. This is what I changed from the above code.

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views','./views');

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.pug");
});
```

Then I made a little change to that code block. I changed **res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.pug")** as **res.render(__dirname + "/views/index.pug")**. It outputs the 'index.pug' file in the browser but when I submit the form with details it does nothing. This is my 'pug' file.

```
html
    head
        title MongoDB

body
    form(action = '/person', method = 'POST')
    br
    div
    label Enter Your Name: 
    input(type = 'text', name = 'name')
    br
    div
    label Enter Your Age: 
    input(type = 'number', name = 'age')
    br
    div
    label Enter Your Nationality: 
    input(type = 'text', name = 'nationality')
    br
    div
    button(type = 'submit') Submit
```

Please help me to modify this code to submit data using 'pug' files instead of 'html' files. (Actually I found several ways to use 'pug + expressjs + mongoose'. Since those are very different ways, I could not be able to modify **this code**. That's why I'm requesting help from the community... Thank You! )

Comment: `.sendFile()` just sends whatever file, as it is. Browsers have no idea what a Pug file is. For them, it's just a text file. So they download it. `.render()` is totally different. It "bakes" (transpiles) the Pug code into proper HTML, and then sends this HTML to the browser, which then displays it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @JeremyThille

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `sendFile` only works with **static** files as specified in the static middleware. `pug` files are not understood by the browser, so cannot be displayed.
2. Pug relies on indentation, so...

```
html
    head
        title MongoDB

body
    form(action = '/person', method = 'POST')
        br
        div
        label Enter Your Name: 
        input(type = 'text', name = 'name')
        br
        div
        label Enter Your Age: 
        input(type = 'number', name = 'age')
        br
        div
        label Enter Your Nationality: 
        input(type = 'text', name = 'nationality')
        br
        div
        button(type = 'submit') Submit
```

will add all inputs and labels inside the form, while your code will put them outside the form rendering the form useless.

Comment: I think `pug files are dynamic => cannot be sent` is totally wrong. Pug files are simple text files. Of course they can be sent. The only thing is, browsers have no idea how to display them, so they download them.